# can't push origin to master on git - repository not found

Tags: git, github, commit

I'm working my way through a git/git hub tutorial (very new at this) on Windows 7 machine. I am trying to push origin to master.  I tried as follows:

```
C:\Users\Home Office\Desktop\Projects\myproject>git push -u origin mas
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': zonk3
Password for 'https://zonk3@github.com':
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/zonk3/myproject.git/' not found

C:\Users\Home Office\Desktop\Projects\myproject>git push origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': zonk3
Password for 'https://zonk3@github.com':
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/zonk3/myproject.git/' not found
```

It prompts me to log into github via gui, then on the command line, then says it can't find the repository. However when I look for the repository I can see it.

```
C:\Users\Home Office\Desktop\Projects\myproject>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/zonk3/myproject.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/zonk3/myproject.git (push)
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your username is `Zonk3` rather than `zonk3`. Not sure if git is case sensitive or not, but it is worth changing the URL for the origin remote to test it out.

Comment: Is this a private repo or did you change the name to myproject on purpose? I am not seeing a repo for that project https://github.com/Zonk3?tab=repositories You will need to add the repo if that is the name git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git

Comment: Josh, I'm not following this.  myproject is the name of the repo i created. 
C:\Users\Home Office\Desktop\Projects\myproject>git remote add origin https://gi
thub.com/zonk3/myproject.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys thanks for the help.  I think I solved this and Josh was on the right track.  I created the repo using the GitHub desktop (as opposed to website) and as a result the repo didn't seem to exist.  When I created a new repo via website the project worked perfectly.  Sadly, I guess the direction i couldn't follow properly was "open GitHub."  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The remote repository addition command seems quite not right on given example.

The correct adding syntax would be

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/zonk3/myproject.git
```

But first of all make sure to initiate the git repo on working folder with following command

`git init`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps, you could try `git remote rm origin` first